# Sending directly from one channel to another

Tags: go, channel

I stumbled upon what I found to be surprising behavior when sending from one channel directly to another channel:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    my_chan := make(chan string)
    chan_of_chans := make(chan chan string)

    go func() {
        my_chan <- "Hello"
    }()

    go func() {
        chan_of_chans <- my_chan
    }()

    fmt.Println(<- <- chan_of_chans)
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ClYjSrGdPM)

I expected `<- my_chan` to send `"Hello"` type `string`. However, it sends type `chan string` and my code runs fine. This means that what is being (`string` or `chan string`) sent depends on the type of the receiver.

I tried naive googling, but since I am not familiar with proper terminology I came up with nothing. Is there a proper term associated with the above behavior? Any additional insight is great of course.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but let's give it a shot.

Consider this line:

```
chan_of_chans <- my_chan
```

What you're actually doing is pushing `my_chan` into the channel, rather than removing something from `my_chan` and pushing it into `chan_of_chans`.

If you want to extract something from `my_chan` and send it to another channel, you need to extract it by using the `<-` operator right before the channel without a space:

```
value := <-my_chan
other_chan <- value
```

Alternatively, this should work:

```
other_chan <- (<-my_chan)
```